# XSLT - Recursive templates

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, recursion

I'm new of XSLT and I have troubles with template recursive.
My problem is: I have two file xml, the first is:

```
    <EV>
        <forma codice="f01">
            ...
            <forma codice="f02">
                ...
                <forma>
                    ...
                </forma>
            </forma>
        </forma>
    </EV>
```

and the second is:

```
<forme> <!--codice_forma è "fxx"-->
<famiglia tipo="quadrilatero">
    <forma codice="f00" figura="quadrato"/>
    <forma codice="f01" figura="rettangolo"/>
</famiglia>
<famiglia tipo="triangolo">
    <forma codice="f02" figura="triangolo equilatero"/>
    <forma codice="f03" figura="triangolo rettangolo"/>
</famiglia>
</forme>
```

Now I must have this trasform result, with the join on attributes "codice":

```
<EV>
        <forma tipo="quadrilatero" figura="rettangolo">
           <forma ...>
               <forma ...>
                   ...
               </forma>
           </forma>
        </forma>
</EV>
```

My XSLT file don't include the tags "forma":

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <evoluzione>
        <!-- Ciclo su tutti i possibili snapshot presenti -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/evoluzione/snapshot">
            <!-- Creo il tag snapshot -->
            <snapshot id="{@id}" label="{@label}">
                <!-- Creo il tag data -->
                <data giorno="{substring(@data,1,2)}" mese="{substring(@data,4,2)}" anno="{substring(@data,7,4)}"/>
                <!-- Ciclo su tutti i possibili esseri viventi presenti nello shapshot -->
                <xsl:for-each select="./EV">
                    <!-- Creo il tag EV -->
                    <EV cod_individuo="{@codice_individuo}" eta="{@eta}" salute="{@salute}" ciclo_di_vita="{@ciclo_di_vita}">
                        <!-- Invoco template sul file esseri_vienti.xml per ricavare l'aspettativa -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('/home/localhero/Scrivania/Progetto/esseri_viventi.xml')//EV">
                            <!-- Passo il parametro codInd al template -->
                            <xsl:with-param name="codInd" select="@codice_individuo"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        <!-- Creo il tag specie -->
                        <specie>
                            <!-- Invoco template sul file tipi_esseri_viventi.xml -->
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('/home/localhero/Scrivania/Progetto/tipi_esseri_viventi.xml')//tipo">
                                <!-- Passo il parametro codTip al template -->
                                <xsl:with-param name="codTip" select="@codice_tipo"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </specie>
                        <!-- Creo il tag matrice -->
                        <matrice>
                            <!-- Qui andranno i tag di <affinità specie>%</affinità> -->
                        </matrice>
                        <!--THE TROUBLE IS THERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-->
                        <!-- Invoco template sul file forme.xml -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('/home/localhero/Scrivania/Progetto/forme.xml')//forma">
                            <!-- Passo il parametro codForm al template -->
                            <xsl:with-param name="codForm" select=".//forma/@codice"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>


                    </EV>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </snapshot>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </evoluzione>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Richiamo template su tutti i nodi EV del file esseri_viventi.xml-->
<xsl:template match="EV">
    <!-- Parametro codInd ricevuto in input dal template -->
    <xsl:param name="codInd"/>
    <!-- Se l'attributo Stringa non è NULL -->
    <xsl:if test="@Stringa != ''">
        <!-- Espressione regolare sull'attributo Stringa -->
        <xsl:analyze-string select="@Stringa" regex="(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <!-- Se il codice individuo coincide allora crea l'attributo aspettativa -->
                <xsl:if test="$codInd = regex-group(2)">
                    <xsl:attribute name="aspettativa">
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(6)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Richiamo template su tutti i nodi tipo del file esseri_viventi.xml-->
<xsl:template match="tipo">
    <!-- Parametro codTip ricevuto in input dal template -->
    <xsl:param name="codTip"/>
    <!-- Se il codice tipo coincide allora crea gli attributi -->
    <xsl:if test="$codTip = @codice">
        <xsl:attribute name="famiglia">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@nome"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="nome_specie">
            <xsl:value-of select="@specie"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Richiamo template su tutti i nodi forma del file forme.xml-->
<xsl:template match="forma">
    <!-- Parametro codForm ricevuto in input dal template -->
    <xsl:param name="codForm"/>
    <!-- Se il codice forma coincide allora crea gli attributi -->
    <xsl:if test="$codForm = @codice">
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="$codForm"/><br/>-->
        <!-- Creo il tag forma -->
        <forma>
            <xsl:attribute name="tipo">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@tipo"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="figura">
                <xsl:value-of select="@figura"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- Ricorsione -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="forma">
                <!-- Passo il parametro codForm al template -->
                <xsl:with-param name="codForm" select="document('/home/localhero/Scrivania/Progetto/evoluzione.xml')//forma/@codice"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </forma>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My results:

```
   ...
   <EV>
        <forma tipo="quadrilatero" figura="rettangolo"></forma>
        <forma tipo="triangolo" figura="triangolo equilatero"></forma>
        <forma ...></forma>
        <forma ...></forma>
        ...
        <forma ...></forma>
    </EV>
```

Why the recursion don't work? Why don't include in mode recursive the tags "forma" in this way:

```
<forma>
  <forma>
     ...
  </forma>
</forma>
```

Thanks very much for your patience and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest possible stylesheet to do what you need looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="forme" select="document('/path/to/forme.xml')//forma" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="forma/@codice">
    <xsl:variable name="forma" select="$forme[@codice = current()]" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$forma/@figura | $forma/../@tipo" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes

- Since you want to output the same structure as the `<EV>` document, you must (well... *should*) apply the stylesheet to *that* document, not to the lookup document.
- "Keeping the same structure" always means to start with the identity template and override it as needed.
- In this case we need to replace all `codice` attributes of `<forma>` elements, so we only need a template that matches `forma/@codice` and outputs different attributes.
- `$forme[@codice = current()]` selects the matching `<forma>` from the lookup document.
- `$forma/@figura | $forma/../@tipo` selects the two attribute nodes we need.
- The solution assumes that `@codice` numbers are uniqe in the lookup document.

The output looks like this, for your sample:

```
<EV>
    <forma tipo="quadrilatero" figura="rettangolo">
        <!-- ... -->
        <forma tipo="triangolo" figura="triangolo equilatero">
            <!-- ... -->
            <forma>
                <!-- ... -->
            </forma>
        </forma>
    </forma>
</EV>
```

Comment: You have `<xsl:variable name="codice" select="document('/path/to/forme.xml')//forma" />` but then reference `$forme[@codice = current()]`. Looks like you want `$codice[@codice = current()]`.

Comment: @Martin Oops, copy/paste mistake. I actually wanted the variable to be named `$forme`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I don't understand how integrate this code in my xslt document :( My xslt file contain more code (for this I put the "..." in the code). Now I have paste your code at the end of the my file and the result is:
<EV ..>
<forma tipo="quadrilatero" figura="quadrato"></forma>
<forma tipo="quadrilatero" figura="rettangolo"></forma>
<forma tipo="triangolo" figura="triangolo equilatero"></forma>
<forma tipo="triangolo" figura="triangolo rettangolo"></forma>
</EV>

Comment: To answer this I would need to see the rest of your stylesheet.

Comment: Ok, now I edit my question with the rest of my stylesheet! Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I have edit my question. I'm sorry for my ignorance but I have begin from bit with xslt and I have trouble for a project for the university.

Comment: The main trouble is that you use `<xsl:for-each>`. That's not the way XSLT is supposed to work and you should not use it, especially as a beginner (and it's incompatible with my approach). I'll try and fix your stylesheet.

Comment: Also - XSLT 1.0 does not support `<xsl:analyze-string>`. Are you sure the code you posted is correct?

Comment: Yes, <xsl:analyze-string> work well! I use it for the regular expression ;)
Thanks, thanks, thanks!!! @Tomalak sorry for the disturbance!

Comment: It would help if you posted the input XML documents as well - maybe to http://pastebin.com/, along with the expected output XML. Cut them down to the absolute minimum, if possible.

Comment: pastebin.com is offlin now. This is a link of google drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B76fwAJ6clQrd3pQc0NGYWhmNHc&usp=sharing)

Comment: @Tomalak I have noted that don't enter in the `<xsl:apply-templates select="forma">
<xsl:with-param name="codForm" select="document('/home/localhero/Scrivania/Progetto/evoluzione.xml')//forma/@codice"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>` because I have commented this block of code and the result is the same!

Comment: Yes, as I said, your entire stylesheet does not follow the right usage paradigm for XSLT. I'm not sure whether I manage to understand all files you gave me today. Could be tomorrow before you hear back from me.

Comment: Okok, sorry for the time that I've stolen to you! But thanks for your help :)

Comment: Look at this: http://pastebin.com/jWp4aETF. With the files you gave me this creates exactly the output you need. The two templates from my answer fit in nicely, not a single `<xsl:for-each>` was used and the code is a lot less deeply nested. Try to go on in this style. You will have to understand how the *identity template* works first, so I suggest you read about that. The general approach is: The identity template does all the recursion and the copying. Your job is to write templates *only* for the nodes that you want to change.

Comment: Thanks my friend!!! :) Only a thing: in what file must I put the <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourfile.xslt"?> ???

Comment: @Tomalak I have this error: HTTP ERROR 400

Problem accessing /exist/rest/db/Basi2B/evoluzione.xml. Reason:

    Error while serializing XML: Ambiguous rule match for /comment()[1]
Matches both "comment()" on line -1 of 
and "node()" on line -1 of

Comment: Don't see this line, if comment go work: <xsl:template match="comment()" />
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" />

Comment: I've tested my code with the files you gave me and it works. It's fair to say that you should debug this one yourself.

Comment: If I put: `<xsl:template match="//comment()" />
  <xsl:template match="//processing-instruction()" />`, work well!!

Comment: I have another bit problem: now I must to continue the xslt, I don't must print the tag <coordinate> but I must print the tag <punto> in this way: <punto x="value" y="value"/>. Example: <forma ...><punto x="2" y="0"/><punto ...>...</forma>

Comment: Well, first you write a template that transforms a `<punto>` from the input into the right format. That's exactly three lines of code. Then you use that template via an `<xsl:apply-templates>` call in the right spot. That's exactly one line of code. I will not show you, because I'm sure you will find out if you think about it some more.

Comment: Is this the match for the template? `<xsl:template match="punto">
    <xsl:attribute name="x" select="x"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="y" select="y"/>
  </xsl:template>`
The call template: `...<matrice></matrice>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="forma"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="punto"/>...` ???

Comment: Think about it. Currently `<forma>` is handled by the identity template, which means it (and all children in it) are copied. The only reason why you don't see `<coordinate>` in the output is because it is suppressed by the empty template at the end of the XSLT. Now modify the `coordinate` template. Make it apply templates to `<punto>` within. See what happens with the output. Now write a template for `punto` that will output the right format.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40816/discussion-between-tomalak-and-local-hero)